# Prediction intervals of a log return time series when converting back to levels

Tags: time-series, arima, prediction, logarithm

I am having a problem when calculating prediction intervals of an ARIMA model of a log return transformed time series.

Assume I have the following point estimates for $h \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ where $y_{t+h}$ is my predicted value (in log returns, meaning $y_i = \log(l_i) - \log(l_{i-1})$, where $l_i$ is my actual observation in levels):

$y_{t+1} = 0.01 $

$y_{t+2} = 0.02 $

$y_{t+3} = 0.025 $

Further, my last observed level $l_t$ at time $t$ is $100$. Hence, my point estimate in levels for $h \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ is:

$l_{t+1} = 100 \cdot e^{y_{t+1}} = 100 \cdot e^{0.01} \approx 101 $

$l_{t+2} = 100 \cdot e^{0.01} \cdot e^{0.02} \approx 103 $

$l_{t+3} = 0100 \cdot e^{0.01} \cdot e^{0.02} \cdot e^{0.025} \approx 106$

Additionally, assume the variance of the model to be $\sigma^2 = 0.01$. The $\alpha = 80\%$ prediction interval for $y_{t+1}$ will then be:

$PI_{y_{t+1},0.8} = y_{t+1} \pm \sigma \cdot \Phi(1 - (1-\alpha)/2) = 0.01 \pm 0.1 \cdot \Phi(0.9) \approx 0.01 \pm 0.128$

Which results in a prediction interval for $l_{t+1}$

$PI_{l_{t+1},0.8} = 100 \cdot e^{PI_{y_{t+1},0.8}} \approx 100 \cdot e^{0.01 \pm 0.128} \approx \{89,115\}$

From here on, I am unsure how to continue. Calculating the $PI$ for $h=2$ in logdiffs should still be somewhat easy (even though I am also not 100% sure here):

$PI_{y_{t+2},0.8} = y_{t+2} \pm \sigma \cdot \sqrt{h} \cdot \Phi(1 - (1-\alpha)/2)$

Where I took the added part of $\sqrt{h}$ from https://otexts.com/fpp2/prediction-intervals.html

When applying this to $PI$ of levels, I came up with a few options:

1. $PI_{1.,l_{t+2},0.8} = l_{t+2} \cdot e^{PI_{y_{t+2},0.8}}$

   - Likely too narrow, as it is not accounting for the variance in the previously predicted period
2. $PI_{2.,l_{t+2},0.8} = PI_{l_{t+1},0.8} \cdot e^{PI_{y_{t+2},0.8}}$

   - Likely too wide, as multiplying the previous level $PI_l$ with the exponential of $PI_y$ would give me the corridor in which only $0.2^2 = 0.04$ of predictions fall (wouldn't it?), because $P[y_{t+1} \notin PI_{y_{t+1},0.8}] = 0.2$, $P[y_{t+2} \notin PI_{y_{t+2},0.8}] = 0.2$, and thus,

   $P[y_{t+1} \notin PI_{y_{t+1},0.8} \wedge y_{t+2} \notin PI_{y_{t+2},0.8}] = P[y_{t+1} \notin PI_{y_{t+1},0.8}] \cdot P[y_{t+2} \notin PI_{y_{t+2},0.8}] = 0.2 \cdot 0.2 = 0.04$

   (if they are independent events?)
3. Adjusting the corridor for each $h$, so that they multiply to the desired prediction interval in the end.

Option 3 would like look like this:

1. I know that my prediction interval should be $0.8$, meaning that the combined probability of observations laying outside is $0.2$. Using the logic from option 2 above, I calculate new prediction intervals $PI_{y_{t+h},\alpha_h}$ for each $h$, where $1 - \alpha_h = 0.2^{1/h}$, so that they multiply to $0.2$ for the prediction interval for the level ($PI_{3.,l_{t+h},0.8}$) in the end.
2. The prediction interval is then calculated by:

   $PI_{3.,l_{t+h},0.8} = l_t \cdot \prod^h_{i=1} e^{PI_{y_{t+i},\alpha_h}} = l_t \cdot \prod^h_{i=1} e^{y_{t+i} \pm \sigma \cdot \sqrt{i} \cdot \Phi(1 - (1-\alpha_h)/2)}$

For $h=2$ and $l_t = 100$:

$PI_{3.,l_{t+2},0.8} = 100 \cdot e^{PI_{y_{t+1},\alpha_2}} \cdot e^{PI_{y_{t+2},\alpha_2}}$

where $1 - \alpha_2 = 0.2^{1/2} \approx 0.45 $ and thus,

\begin{align}PI_{y_{t+1},\alpha_2} &= y_{t+1} \pm \sigma \cdot \Phi(1 - (1-\alpha_2)/2) \\ 
&\approx 0.01 \pm \sigma \cdot \Phi(1 - 0.45/2) \\
&= 0.01 \pm \sigma \cdot \Phi(0.775) \\
&\approx \{-0.0655,0.0855\}\end{align}

and

\begin{align}PI_{y_{t+2},\alpha_2} &= y_{t+2} \pm \sigma \cdot \Phi(1 - (1-\alpha_2)/2) \\ 
&\approx 0.02 \pm \sigma \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \Phi(1 - 0.45/2) \\
&= 0.02 \pm \sigma \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \Phi(0.775) \\
&\approx \{-0.0868,0.1268\}.\end{align}

Finally, the upper $PI$:

$PI_{3.,l_{t+2},0.8, upper} \approx 100 \cdot e^{0.0855} \cdot e^{0.1268} \approx 123.65 $

and lower $PI$:

$PI_{3.,l_{t+2},0.8, lower} \approx 100 \cdot e^{-0.0655} \cdot e^{-0.0868} \approx 85.87 $

for $h=3$ these steps will be done equivalently.

Now, is this option 3 the correct solution? Or is there anything I missed or did wrong?

I hope I was correct in all my notations and made my problem clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't just exponentiate logged predictions to get back to levels because of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: So, which step is wrong? Converting from logdiffs back to level (e.g. how I calculated the point estimate of $l_{t+1}$)? Should I not convert my time series to logdiffs to begin with?